# Block text drag in contenteditable element

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<a href="#" contenteditable>Select some of this text, then drag and drop it around.</a>
```

If I select text in the contenteditable element, I can drag that text elsewhere in the element.

How do I block this event? Prevent text from being draggable? But still editable and selectable?

Comment: Cancel [dragstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragstart) event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('a')[0].ondragstart = function () { return false; };
```

```html
<!--using script tag -->
<a  href="#" contenteditable>Select some of this text, then drag and drop it around.</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ondragstart="return false"`

```html
<a ondragstart="return false"  href="#" contenteditable>Select some of this text, then drag and drop it around.</a>
```